# How to communicate between discord.py and Tweepy?

Tags: python, asynchronous, discord.py, python-asyncio, tweepy

My code is is similar to this example:

```
import discord
import tweepy 
import asyncio

class Client(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("ready")
        global GUILD
        GUILD = discord.utils.get(self.guilds, name = "Any Guild")

class TweepyStream(tweepy.Stream):
    def on_connect(self):
        print("connceted")

    def on_status(self, status):
        print(status.text)
        channel = discord.utils.get(GUILD.channels, name = "twitter-posts")
        asyncio.run(channel.send(status.text))
        #From here the Discord message should be send




auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(keys)
auth.set_access_token(tokens)
global api
api = tweepy.API(auth)

follow_list = []
follow = int(api.get_user(screen_name = "Any User").id)
print(follow)
follow_list.append(follow)
print(str(follow_list))

stream = TweepyStream(tokens and keys)
stream.filter(follow = follow_list,  threaded=True) #track = track,


client = Client()
client.run(token)
```

I try to receive Twitter posts and send them into a Discord channel, but it doesn't work. How can I do this (maybe without asyncio)?
Or is there a way to work with a Python Twitter API, which works with async functions?

My error:

```
Stream encountered an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 133, in _connect
    self.on_data(line)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 387, in on_data
    return self.on_status(status)
  File "c:\Users\morit\Desktop\FLL 2021 Bot\DiscordBot\DiscordBotV0.7\example.py", line 18, in on_status
    asyncio.run(channel.send(status.text))
  File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "C:\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 642, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 1065, in send
    data = await state.http.send_message(channel.id, content, tts=tts, embed=embed,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 192, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as r:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\client.py", line 448, in _request
    with timer:
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\aiohttp\helpers.py", line 635, in __enter__
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`asyncio.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) creates a new event loop. You need to use the existing event loop that the [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client) uses. You can retrieve this with [`Client.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.loop), [`asyncio.get_running_loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_running_loop), or [`asyncio.get_event_loop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop).

You should probably also use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe).

If you're using the current latest development version of Tweepy on the master branch, set to be released as v4.0, which it seems like you are, then you can also look into using [`AsyncStream`](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asyncstream.html#tweepy.asynchronous.AsyncStream)